# Error using uchar opencv

Tags: opencv

With

```
Mat Image = Imgcodecs.imread(filePath);
int totalBytes = (int)(Image.total()*Image.elemSize());
Mat m = new Mat(Image.rows(), Image.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(1,3,5));
Imgproc.cvtColor(Image, m, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
Scalar intensity = m.at<uchar>(16,16);
```

I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable at   location:
>   variable m of type org.opencv.core.Mat

Can someone tell me what can i do ?

Comment: Add some more code to see the context.

Comment: Mat Image = Imgcodecs.imread(filePath);
   int totalBytes = (int)(Image.total()*Image.elemSize());
                        Mat m = new Mat(Image.rows(), Image.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(1,3,5));
                        Imgproc.cvtColor(Image, m, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
                        Scalar intensity =  m.at<uchar>(16,16);